# Parse and changing data value in a xml file using lua

Tags: xml, lua

Referred from this topic : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32878542d

How to parse data from xml file and change value, using lua without any special lua library ?

Example : **MyTest.xml**

```
<mapList>
<map>
<type>No Maps</type>
<packId>8060</packId>
<id>1</id>
<name>No Maps</name>
<desc>No Maps</desc>
<funnyDesc>So much of life, it seems to me, is determined by pure randomness. - Sidney Poitier</funnyDesc>
<mapData>
<node row="0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
<node row="0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
<node row="0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0"/>
<node row="3,3,3,3,0,0,0,3,3,3"/>
<node row="3,3,3,3,3,0,3,3,3,3"/>
<node row="1,5,2,3,0,0,3,3,3,3"/>
<node row="3,3,3,3,0,0,0,3,3,3"/>
<node row="3,3,3,3,3,0,3,3,3,3"/>
<node row="1,5,2,3,0,0,3,3,3,3"/>
<node row="3,3,3,3,0,0,0,3,3,3"/>
<node row="3,3,3,3,3,0,3,3,3,3"/>
<node row="1,5,2,3,0,0,3,3,3,3"/>
<node row="3,3,3,3,0,0,0,3,3,3"/>
<node row="3,3,3,3,3,0,3,3,3,3"/>
<node row="1,5,2,3,0,0,3,3,3,3"/>
<node row="3,3,3,3,0,0,0,3,3,3"/>
<node row="3,3,3,3,3,0,3,3,3,3"/>
<node row="1,5,2,3,0,0,3,3,3,3"/>
<node row="3,3,3,3,0,0,0,3,3,3"/>
<node row="3,3,3,3,3,0,3,3,3,3"/>
</mapData>
</map>
```

I want get all `node row="3,3,3,3,3,0,3,3,3,3"` and change to `node row="1,5,2,3,0,0,3,3,3,3"` which identify by `<type>`, `<packId>`, `<id>` and `<name>`.

Any help should be appreciate..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32878542/i-use-lua-5-1-i-want-to-parse-an-xml-file-of-the-following-pattern-how-should?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

```
local file = assert(io.open("myTest.xml"))
local xml = file:read"*a"
file:close()

xml = xml:gsub("<map>.-</map>",
   function(s)
      local typ = s:match"<type>(.-)</type>"
      local packId = s:match"<packId>(.-)</packId>"
      local id = s:match"<id>(.-)</id>"
      local name = s:match"<name>(.-)</name>"
      if
         typ    == "No Maps" and
         packId == "8060"    and
         id     == "1"       and
         name   == "No Maps"
      then
         return s:gsub("<mapData>.-</mapData>",
            function(s)
               return s:gsub('<node row="3,3,3,3,3,0,3,3,3,3"/>', 
                             '<node row="1,5,2,3,0,0,3,3,3,3"/>')
            end
         )
      end
   end
)

local file = assert(io.open("myTest2.xml", "w"))
file:write(xml)
file:close()
```

Comment: Work like a charm. Thank you very much. @Egor Skriptunoff